# Compute PERCENTILE in MS Excel when some values are error values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, percentile

Computing 90% percentile of integers in range say `A1:A10` can be done by the formula `=PERCENTILE(A1:A10, 0.9)`. This works well generally but if one or more cells in the range `A1:A10` is an error (marked as `#N/A`), then the percentile value computed is also `#N/A`.

Is it possible, using only Excel formulas, to compute percentile for all values (except the cells containing error values) in range `A1:A10`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Excel 2010` or later versions you can use `AGGREGATE` function for this, `AGGREGATE` has an option to ignore error values, so you can use this formula

`=AGGREGATE(16,6,A1:A10,0.9)`

See help for `AGGREGATE` function for more details but `16` denotes the function type - in this case `PERCENTILE.INC` (the equivalent of `PERCENTILE` in earlier versions) and `6` means `"ignore errors"`

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
=PERCENTILE(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A10),A1:A10),0.9)
```

with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Courtesy [Dominic](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/407917-quartile-percentile-function-range-containing-n.html).